# Flask-Security error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I have setup a flask-security app, but I'm getting an error creating users and resetting passwords.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__ 
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_securit /decorators.py", line 230, in wrapper
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 118, in register
  user = register_user(**form.to_dict())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_security/registerable.py", line 41, in register_user
  'welcome', user=user, confirmation_link=confirmation_link)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_security/utils.py", line 401, in send_mail
  mail.send(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
  message.send(connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
  connection.send(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 188, in send
  self.host.sendmail(sanitize_address(envelope_from or message.sender),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 105, in sanitize_address
  nm, addr = addr

ValueError: too many values to unpack    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I just followed the guide from https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#basic-sqlalchemy-application

I need help finding out what is wrong.

Here is my e-mail config:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'devskovsted@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '**********'
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'devskovsted@gmail.com'
mail = Mail(app)
```

/Kresten

Comment: Can you show us which line of the code triggers that error, and which version of Python you are running?

Comment: I just updated the question with the full error. I'm running with python 2.7. I'll try to opdate to python 3.6

Comment: I did upgrade to python 3.5, 
 but I just got a new error: 
TypeError: b'918dfe1d793500723996256a8625314f1b4353e1' is not JSON serializable

Comment: try setting the SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER application setting.  The issue tracker has a closed issue that sounds similar: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/685

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which version of Flask-Security you're running (or any other requirements.txt entries you may have).

Comment: Flask-Login      0.4.1  
Flask-Mail       0.9.1  
Flask-Principal  0.4.0  
Flask-Security   3.0.0  
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2  
Flask-WTF        0.14.2 
itsdangerous     0.24   
Jinja2           2.10   
MarkupSafe       1.0    
passlib          1.7.1  
pycparser        2.18   
pytz             2018.4 
setuptools       39.1.0 
six              1.11.0 
speaklater       1.3    
SQLAlchemy       1.2.7  
Werkzeug         0.14.1 
wheel            0.31.0 
WTForms          2.1

Comment: Cool-- so, did setting SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER work?  If not, since we know the error is to do with the Flask-Mail part of the package, can you include your code for that?

Comment: SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER didn't do any difference. I have added my e-mail config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with the send_mail method in flask-security utils ref this [thread](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/685#ref-commit-241acf2) .

It is corrected in this [branch](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security)

One way out is to uninstall flask-security and install the updated repo

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security
```

Of course depending on your settings you may want to do `sudo pip install`

Comment: That did it.  Why is this still an issue with Flask-Security